# What can I do about a low spot in my bathroom floor?

Tags: bathroom, floor

I have water standing on a specific area of my bathroom floor. The whole floor dries out except for this area. It has stagnant standing water.
What can be causing this problem, and is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: where is your home located, and what sort of construction is it? cinder block, wood frame, concrete? what's your floor material? tile, vinyl, stone?

Comment: It is a house and washroom is the ensuite. It is built of brown square tiles. The area bordering the shower room is where the water keeps standing otherwise whole washroom dries up quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you expect your floor to drain or dry? Is this a wet room, where the whole floor area is designed to get wet and drain? In most bathrooms (at least in the US), only the bath/shower itself is designed to drain water. The rest of the floor is typically made of a material that won't be damaged by an occasional splash but also isn't designed to drain large amounts of water.

If you have a wet room with areas that don't drain, then the solution is to fix the shape of the floor so those areas do drain. The exact approach (and how invasive the repair would be) depends on your particular layout and materials.

If you have a more typical bathroom, then you should not expect the floor to function as a drain, and instead work to prevent it from getting quite so wet. Often this can be solved with better placement of shower curtains and bath mats or repair of leaks. For advice on that we'd need to know where this water is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've pointed out to me from my original answer that this certainly is not a leak related puddle & is just a usage remnant puddle due to a low-spot in the tile. Then, you have 4 main options to choose from:

1 - Treat the puddle area like a street pothole & fill in the area with cement.

2 - Chisel up the puddle area's tiles, level the floor beneath & install new tiles.

3 - Double Option: A - Perform #1 & install new tiles over the entire floor of old tiles. B - Install cement on top of the old tiles & sculpt it to pitch the floor toward the drain prior to installing new tiles. Either of these raises the floor & may therefore cause problems with fixtures &/or doors.

4 - Remove the whole floor's tiles, repair or flatten the floor, pitch the floor with cement toward the drain & install all new tile.